# I get translated text when I do a GET request (in Python). How to get English content?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, ip-address

I'm trying to web scrape [this page](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1&ref_=adv_nxt) for fun.

The script is working fine, but the names of **some** movies are translated into Romanian (for example, *"Beauty and the Beast"* is *"Frumoasa si Bestia"*).

I'm guessing that the server is sending me the requested content depending on my IP.

However, in my browser I see only English names, no matter if I use my IP or activate a VPN through a browser's extension. It's probably because the browser's language is set to English and translate option is off.

My question is this: how to get all the names in English?

Can I specify some parameter in my `GET` request to do that?

```
import requests
page = requests.get(some_URL)
```

I was also thinking about using a server VPN (not just a browser extension), but I'm running on Lubuntu and there seems to be a lot headache in installing a free VPN (accounts to be made etc.).

If it helps, I use Jupyter Notebook to code.

Comment: We can't really answer that. It's not a Python problem. HTTP servers are black boxes; we can't see inside them to determine how they make decisions. You'll have to experiment; check what your browser sends (use your browser developer tools, look at the headers and query string), then see what you need to replicate.

Comment: Why is this tagged HTML????

Comment: @SankarshMakam, sorry, I was "thinking" for a fraction of second that since I was parsing the request's content as HTML, that might somehow be relevant. But it's not. Just removed it, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this site is serving pages based on browser language. Try to set it on requests:

```
import requests

url = r"http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&page=1&ref_=adv_nxt"
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

By the way. Check imdb web scrape's policy.